# SQL for string more than 255 chars

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle

I am trying to find a way to manipulate values that are returned as part of a query. Basically, if the value is less than 255 char, use this value but if value is more than 255 characters, need to return a string "value more than 255 characters" instead of actual value. I need to achieve this a part of SQL query. Appreciate any feedback.Thanks Jay

Comment: Are you using SQL Server?  Or Oracle?  They have different functions for calculating the length of a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming SQL Server, try this which uses the [`LEN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx) function combined with a [`CASE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx):

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN LEN(StringColumn) > 255 
        THEN 'value more than 255 characters' 
        ELSE StringColumn 
    END As MyColumnName
FROM MyTable
```

Example sqlfiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e0508/1/0

Edit: In case you are using Oracle as the tags suggest, instead of `LEN`, use [`LENGTH`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions076.htm):

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN LENGTH(StringColumn) > 255 
        THEN 'value more than 255 characters' 
        ELSE StringColumn 
    END As MyColumnName
FROM MyTable
```

Example sqlfiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9bc74/2/0

Answer (score 1):

The following `CASE` pattern will work with most systems:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN LENGTH(someCol) <= 255 
    THEN someCol
    ELSE "value more than 255 characters"
  END AS ColName 
FROM
  TableName
```

Take note that string functions differ depending on your database software.

See:

- **[`CHARACTER_LENGTH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_character-length) for Mysql**, (*[fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/212aa/2)*)
- **[`LEN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx) for SQL Server**, or
- **[`LENGTH`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/length.php) for Oracle**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `LEN()` function to determine the length of the string. Then use a `CASE` conditional structure to determine what value to return.

ref:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx